# CSS color accuracy on different screens

Tags: javascript, css, monitor, color-space

The web site I'm working on makes heavy use of a single color through CSS. I'm trying to make this specific shade look the same on all screens (PC, tablets, and mobile). I'm just hoping that this very old issue has gotten a solution by now.

```
:root 
{
    --fontSize:62.5%;
    --primaryColor:#f6e072;
}

.mainPane 
{
   background-color:var(--primaryColor);
}
```

Colors are never the same between screens, and I usually just ignore it. But in this case the difference is so huge, that I need to do something.

Is there a way to make the color look (mostly) the same on all screens? I've looked into the sRGB and color-gamut of images. I had an idea that I could use the browser's built-in color correction of jpg images, and perhaps sample the pixel colors from the screen, but without any success. I also tried specifying as hsla() instead of hex values, but that makes no difference either. To access the screen's ICC profile from Javascript might be helpful, but I can't see how that is done.

Comment: IMO there is nothing bulltetproof you can do: you cannot fight weird contrast / brightness / temperature settings of every single display device in the wild.  If your colors fit into sRGB gamut (what is granted, CSS cannot currently express colors from wider range), you can watch for relative contrasts and resulting "legibility" of your palette, but cannot prevent concrete over-saturated or bleached-out outcomes.